# How can I create general e-mail in google apps

Tags: google-apps

I am new user of google apps. I have my domain registred but I can not find any information how to create e-mail like: info@domain.com. All e-mails should go to userA@domain.com and userB@domain.com

The only way is to create user 'inf'o and set redirection on its gmail account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a Google Group which accepts incoming mail from non-member accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a nickname 'info' against an existing user.